# How to connect my ionic app with MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, ionic-framework

I am not able to connect to the database what should be the syntax when I have created the database (myDb) using phpMyAdmin. I have placed signup.php on the server i.e www folder.
Please point out if there is some other mistake I have made in this code.

signup.html:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
<h2 class="title">SignUp</h2>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view view-title="SignUp" name="signup-view">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list list-inset">

   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
   <span class="input-label">Enter Username</span>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="userdata.username" placeholder="Enter Username">
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
   <span class="input-label">Enter Your Email</span>
     <input type="text" ng-model="userdata.email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
   </label>

   <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
   <span class="input-label">Enter Your Password</span>
     <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="userdata.password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
   </label>

   <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="signUp(userdata)">SignUp</button><br>
   <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>
   </div>
   </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $email = $postdata->email;
    $password = $postdata->password;
    $username = $postdata->username;

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'') or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());;
    mysql_select_db('myDb', $con);

    $qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where email="' . $email . '"';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

    if($res['cnt']==0){
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) values ("' . $username . '","' . $password . '","' . $email . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);  
        if ($qry_res) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "2";;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

app.js:

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.signup = function () {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost/signup.php",
        crossDomain : true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {
            username: $scope.userdata.username,
            email: $scope.userdata.email,
            password: $scope.userdata.password
        },
    });
        request.success(function(data) {
        if(data == "1"){
         $scope.responseMessage = "Account Created Successfully!";
        }
        if(data == "2"){
         $scope.responseMessage = "Can not Create Account";
        }
        else if(data == "0") {
         $scope.responseMessage = "Email Already Exists"
        }  
    });
}
});
```

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: I need to know the procedure of how to make MySQL talk with my ionic app.

Comment: i dont understand why ppl are down voting my question...!!!

Comment: we are not here for guideance but for problem resolution

Comment: edited my question with code... now let me know the mistakes I have created...

Comment: Please don't copy+paste the entire code, add only the relevant pieces of code. And not lastly, give us all the details about the problem: exact code that doesn't work, what errors do you receive, the connection details (exception the password and/or username)

Comment: well sorry for that.. my problem with the code is it doesnt insert the new entries in the database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$request->email`, `$request->password`, `$request->username` instead of `$postdata->email`, `$postdata->password`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is must, I would recommend looking at [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) which is made for creating APIs.Some other solutions that fits here (probably better than PHP & MySQL for this purpose) are [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.org/) + [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) or [ParseSDK for JavaScript](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide) are something to look at as well. I would recommend Parse since it is very easy to get started with and remove a lot of back end headaches.

Sample example using ionic to access API:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $http.get('API_URL')
        .then(
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.data = data;
                // JSON data returned as response
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(err);
                $scope.err = err;
                // when error occurs
            }
        );
});
```

**View:**

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div> {{ data }} {{ err }} </div>
</ion-content>
```

[Example](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-simple-weather-forecast-app-with-ionic-framework-and-forecastio/107) of usage of JSON data.